# Rationalizing only specific terms in an expression

Tags: expression-manipulation, precision-and-accuracy, expression-form

How can I change an expression like

```
A = (-1. a)/(x + y) - (2.1 b)/(x + y) + 4.1 + 2. x + (3. r s)/(x + y)
```

so that `-1. a` becomes `a`, `2. x` becomes `2 x` and `3. r s` becomes `3 r s` yet `2.1 b` and `4.1` remain unchanged? `Rationalize[A]` almost works except it changes `2.1 b` and `4.1`. The expression could be even more complex.

Answer (score 3):

```
A /. x_Real /; FractionalPart[x] == 0 :> Rationalize[x]
```

> ```
> 4.1 + 2 x - a/(x + y) - (2.1 b)/(x + y) + (3 r s)/(x + y)
> ```

Comment: Perfect!. Thank you. Just what I need.

Comment: Also, `A /. x_Real /; IntegerPart[x] == x :> IntegerPart[x]`

Comment: Again, perfect. Thank you, Bob.